# Как отправить значения формы и получить ответ на этой же странице, или в popup окне

Tags: html, html-form

У меня есть форма. После нажатия кнопки Submit я хочу что бы под формой появилась надпись что данные отправлены. Как мне это седлать при текущей разметки?

```html
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="">
  <input class="textbox" type="text" name="customerName" id="name" placeholder="Имя" />
  <input class="textbox" type="text" name="customerPhone" id="phone" placeholder="Телефон" />
  <input class="textbox" type="text" name="customerEmail" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
  <textarea class="textbox" name="customerRequest" id="message" placeholder="Комментарий" style="height: 25px;"></textarea>

  <br />

  <div class="full-width">
    <input type="checkbox" />Я согласен с условиями политики конфиденциальности. <a href="#">Подробнее</a>
  </div>

  <br />

  <button class="button small-btn" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Отправить</button>

  <br /><br />

  <p id="message-outcome"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: нужно делать AJAX запрос, который будет отправлять данные формы на сервер. А на сервере обрабатывать данные и отдавать ответ.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax смотрите.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="" "onsubmit=showMessage();">
  <input class="textbox" type="text" name="customerName" id="name" placeholder="Имя" />
  <input class="textbox" type="text" name="customerPhone" id="phone" placeholder="Телефон" />
  <input class="textbox" type="text" name="customerEmail" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
  <textarea class="textbox" name="customerRequest" id="message" placeholder="Комментарий" style="height: 25px;"></textarea>

  <br />

  <div class="full-width">
    <input type="checkbox" />Я согласен с условиями политики конфиденциальности. <a href="#">Подробнее</a>
  </div>

  <br />

  <button class="button small-btn" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Отправить</button>

  <br /><br />

  <p id="message-outcome" style="display:none;">Ваше сообщение отправлено!</p>
</form>
<script>
function showMessage() {
message = document.getElementById("message-outcome")
message.style.display = "block"
}
</script>
```

Это если вы хотите показывать информационное сообщение о том, что форма отправлена.

Comment: У вас, что же, страница не перезагружается?

Comment: толку от такого?Сообщение показало и все? Надо чтобы данные были отправлены обработаны на сервере и вернулся успех или нет! Иначе это все полная дыра в сайте

Comment: использую razor,  после нажатия я проверяю на isPost и далее уже отправляю на почту данные.